# How to pad string before other string in php?

Tags: php, magento2.2.6

I am using magento 2.2.6. I am showing the amount in particular column.
of my custom page.

E.g

```
CASE - A
```

I have amount say, **`$100.50`**, I want to display amount in the following format:

**`00010050`** (here 3 zeros should be appended before this amount and decimal format should be removed).

```
CASE - B
```

I have amount say, **`$1100.50`**, I want to display amount in the following format:

**`00110050`** (here 2 zeros should be appended before this amount and decimal format should be removed).

Is it possible to append zeros as per amount length and show amount in such format?

Comment: Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this below code :

```
$value = 100.50;
$padding_number = str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo str_replace(".", "", $padding_number);
```